# Is there any English translation of this Gergonne paper?

Tags: mathematics, translations, logic

This is the paper:

“Variétés. Essai de dialectique rationnelle”. Annales de Mathématiques pures et appliquées, tome 7 (1816-1817), p. 189-228

(“Varieties. Essay about rational dialectic”, By J.D. Gergonne).
Between else, in this paper we find the first use of the symbols “C” and “Ɔ”, which later evolved into the modern symbols “$\subset$” and “$\supset$”, used in set theory and, in older texts, for implication.

You can find it [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/AMPA_1816-1817__7__189_0.pdf), in French.

If there isn't any, I believe it deserves one. I would certainly do it, if I could.

---

Copied from [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115262/is-there-any-english-translation-of-this-gergonne-paper), after sugestion from the user Rob Arthan.

Comment: He was [Joseph Diaz Gergonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Diez_Gergonne): M.Gergonne stands for Monsieur (Mr) Gergonne.

Comment: Thanks, I should be more careful.

Comment: I'll look into translating this. I just finished Poisson's first memoir on electricity from french, from around the same time, and I rather like the process of translating anyway.

Comment: @SamGallagher Excellent! When you are done, please let us know how we can access your work.

Comment: @ArisMakrides I did a bit of the introduction and it's quite dense, being mostly about philosophy and whatnot, but it's not impossible. It will be slow going, and its dependent on my free time, so I wouldn't expect a copy in your hand tomorrow. Probably more like 2022... Either way, I'll post it on my history of math and science website: histomathsci.blogspot.com

Comment: @SamGallagher That's OK. Also, if you post an answer here, with a link to your website, I will probably accept it, if no other source has been found by then.

Comment: @ArisMakrides Translation is complete (rough draft) as of today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I'm fond of translating old math and science papers, particularly from French and Latin, I decided to start a new translation project for this work into English. You can check the progress at [my website here](https://histomathsci.blogspot.com/2021/05/translation-of-j-d-gergonnes-varities.html), where I post translations. This project could take some time, if only because the text requires careful reading to ensure the meaning is properly conveyed. I'm hoping to finish by this July.

--Update--

Finished rough draft of the translation May 30, far ahead of schedule (hooray!). The translation is [available here](https://histomathsci.blogspot.com/2021/05/translation-of-j-d-gergonnes-varities.html). Typesetting problems from a previous version are now fixed, but I also posted the original .tex for anyone to experiment with.

Comment: Have you tried machine translation of older texts? I am quite interested in exploring the utility of machine translation in symbolically heavy texts.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that there is an English traslation, and old papers that quote it are in French (e.g. Peano, *Origine du signe $\subset$* in *L'Intermédiaire des Mathématiciens*, 1903, or Giard, *La « dialectique rationnelle » de Gergonne* in *Revue d'histoire des sciences*, 1972, this paper in particular is very interesting, as it gives a detailed analysis of Gergonne's original paper that is not always so clear). Anyway, small parts are reported in the invaluable collection of [Bocheński](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3zef_Maria_Boche%C5%84ski) *Formale Logik* (1956), translated into English as *A history of formal logic* (1961). The translation is easy accessible ([here](https://circulosemiotico.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/historyofformall00boch.pdf) a digitalized copy). You will find some excerps at page 277 ($\S$ 38.15 and 38.16), with this comment of Bocheński "This text is not altogeter clear; Gergonne seems to equate the (Aristotelian) use of variables with formalism. But we can see the idea of formalism becoming clearer", and at page 304 ($\S$ 40.12).

Maybe some other author translated wider excerpt of Gergonne's paper in English, but I haven't been able to find any of them.